# Getting snow in fullscreen video in Google Chrome

Tags: arch-linux, chrome, video

I have Arch Linux running on a Gigabit Z370 HD3P motherboard and i3 CPU with no graphics card (uses onboard video). I have started getting bands of snow when I run fullscreen video only. If I pause the video the snow disappears. If I letterbox the video, the snow goes away, even if the video fills up 95% of the screen. It only happens when the computer is in fullscreen mode.

I recently did a full system upgrade and a lot of stuff was upgraded including Chrome (upgraded to version 81.0.4044.122) and the snow started the first time I ran a video after the upgrade.

The snow only appears so far when I use fullscreen video in Chrome (YoutTube, Vimeo, etc). For example, if I view a test video using VLC (a video player) in fullscreen mode, the video is fine.

How can I further diagnose the problem?